# Quicksort implementation in C using first element as pivot

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am a complete beginner to stackoverflow and this is my first post. Please forgive if this is not the correct place to post these kinds of queries. I have written code for the `Quicksort` algorithm, based on the algorithm given in the Algorithms course in Coursera(It is not for any assignments though).

Basically, there are two functions `Quicksort` which is called *recursively and partition()* function that returns the index of the pivot. I select the pivot as the first element of the array every time. I checked the partition() function and it works fine but the array is not sorted even after I call the `Quicksort()` function.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void swap(int *p, int i, int j)
    {
        int temp = *(p+i);
        *(p+i) = *(p+j);
        *(p+j) = temp;
    }

    int partition(int *q, int l, int r)
    {
        int i = l+1, j;
        int p = l;
        int len  = r-l +1;
        for (j = l+1; j < len; j++)
        {
            /*printf("%d \n", j);*/
            if ( *(q+j) < *(q+p) )
            {
                swap(q, i, j);
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        swap(q, l, i-1);
        /*printf("%d", i-1);*/
        return (i-1);
    }

    void quicksort(int *ptr, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
            int p = partition(ptr, low, high);
            printf("%d\n", p);
            quicksort(ptr, low, p);
            quicksort(ptr, p+1, high);
        }
    }


    int main(){
        int i;
        int a[] = {3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6};
        int len  = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
        for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        int *ptr = a;
        quicksort(ptr, 0, len-1);
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: In my last post i share the c++ example, don't consider it, for C, i am sharing a reference, read this: http://www.cquestions.com/2008/01/c-program-for-quick-sort.html

Comment: `for (j = l+1; j < len; j++)` looks wrong. What if `l` is 7 and `r` is something like 12? `len` is 6 but `j` starts at 8. The for loop will never run.

Answer (score 2):

2 corrections.

Small one: Change 3rd line inside if block in QuickSort function

from

```
quicksort(ptr, low, p);
```

to

```
quicksort(ptr, low, p-1);
```

This will improve performance.

Main error:

Your partition function is wrong. Specifically the loop where `j` runs from `l+1` to `r-l+1`, because, `r-l+1` can be less than `l+1`

I'll write the partition function for you if you want (post a comment if you face any problem with that) though I'd advice you to do it yourself.

EDIT:

A possible partition function:

```
int partition(int *q, int l, int r){
    int i,j;
    int p = *(q + l);
    for(i = l + 1, j = r; ;){
        while(*(q + i) <= p)
            i++;
        while(*(q + j) >= p)
            j--;
        if(i >= j)
            break;
        swap(q, i, j);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in the line quicksort(ptr, low, p). In the loop where j runs from l+1 to r-l+1, I changed it to for (j = l+1; j < r; j++), but it still doesn't work. Can you explain a little more? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply...Didn't check on SO for last few days. I've edited the answer with a possible partition function.

Answer (score 1):

Changes noted in comments.

```
int partition(int *q, int l, int r)
{
    int i = l+1, j;
    int p = l;
                                    /* fix: int len = r-l+1; is not used */
    for (j = l+1; j <= r; j++)      /* fix: j <= r */
    {
        if ( *(q+j) <= *(q+p) )     /* fix: <= */
        {
            swap(q, i, j);
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    swap(q, l, i-1);
    return (i-1);
}

void quicksort(int *ptr, int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int p = partition(ptr, low, high);
        quicksort(ptr, low, p-1);   /* optimization: p-1 */
        quicksort(ptr, p+1, high);
    }
}
```

If interested, Hoare partition scheme is faster. If you switch to this, don't forget to change the two quicksort calls to quicksort(lo, p) and quicksort(p+1, hi) ). You might want to change the Hoare pivot to pivot = A[(lo+hi)/2], which will avoid worst case issue with sorted or reverse sorted array.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme

Comment: thanks. But, I was trying to implement the loops in the partition function so that both i and j start from the lower index, i.e. i from l+1 and j from l+1. Based on your partition function, it seems that my implementation is similar with the only difference being you are decresing the values of i and j in each loop while I am increasing. But, I cannot see why my implementation doesn't work.

Comment: @dwd - I updated my answer to show your implementation with just the changes, three fixes and one optimization. I'll delete this comment later.

Comment: So, in the partition function, the only change from my implementation is that the for loop for j should be for (j = l+1; j <= r; j++), right?

Comment: @dwd - every line with a comment was a fix or in one case an optimization.